# Changes to yml file is not reflecting in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I created a rails app and edited en.yml file under config/locales/views.But the changes to this en.yml is not reflected in production environment(not displayed in my web page)
What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Have yo tried restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the change locally, then you have to deploy the app with the latest code.